# AES Decryption has different behavior in iOS 7 than iOS 8/9

Tags: ios, security, encryption, ios7, aes

The following method returns different results when run on iOS 7 than it does on iOS 8/9.

```
+ (NSData *)decryptData:(NSData *)data key:(NSData *)key iv:(NSData *)iv;
{
  NSData *result = nil;

  // setup key
  unsigned char cKey[FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];
  bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
  [key getBytes:cKey length:FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE];

  // setup iv
  char cIv[FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
  bzero(cIv, FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE);
  if (iv) {
    [iv getBytes:cIv length:FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE];
  }

  // setup output buffer
  size_t bufferSize = [data length] + FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
  void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

  // do decrypt
  size_t decryptedSize = 0;
  CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus =
      CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding, cKey,
              FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE, cIv, [data bytes], [data length], buffer,
              bufferSize, &decryptedSize);

  if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:decryptedSize];
  } else {
    free(buffer);
    NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to decrypt| CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Encryption works on iOS 7/8/9. But the decryption result is nil on iOS 7.

`decryptedSize` is 0 after execution. `buffer` elements remains 0.

Some definitions are

```
#define FBENCRYPT_ALGORITHM kCCAlgorithmAES128
#define FBENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE kCCBlockSizeAES128
#define FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE kCCKeySizeAES256
```

I have read answers to similar `CCCrypt()` questions on SO. Tried the following:

1. Increase `cKey` length by 1
2. Increase `cKey` length to `FBENCRYPT_KEY_SIZE * 2 + 1`
3. Set the first byte of `cKey` to 0 (Some say iOS 6 does this when getting the key bytes from a NSString)

None of the above works.

---

I'm back with some sample data when the method is called.

The three parameters passed to `decryptData` is:

- data: `ea1e6896 b5731f40 1d560a18 f0729fa6`,
- key: `17c76e90 9a6fef8d b1fd45fa 2de18db0 d2236264 db6c8a60 125599ec 2dfb5614`, 256 bits for AES256
- iv: `41463531 38453234 44333835 42463636`, 16-byte which is the same as block size

Expected result (and the actual result on iOS8/9) is `248e51af 66bf85d3 00003ab6 fe3c0000`.

Comment: I've posed a similar question, where instead of a nil result under iOS 7, the plaintext is truncated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850550/ios-7-aes128-decryption-truncates-decrypted-text-no-problems-on-ios-8

Comment: Provide sample input in the form of hex for data (unencrypted and encrypted), key and iv. Of interest is the length of the key and iv, they should be exactly the key length and block size respectively. Note that in some early versions of `CCCrypt` an error would be returned if the padding was incorrect, this was changed to not produce an error as this was a security flaw.

Comment: How is the data encrypted, platform, language and library/function. In particular does the encrypting function use PKCS#7 (or PKCS#5) padding? Note: Do not use FBENCRYPT_* defines instead of the Common Crypto defines, that just adds confusion and another place an error can creep in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick guess since there is little information to go on:

The data was encrypted with a different padding that PKCS#7 (or PKCS#5). `mcrypt()`, while popular was written by some bozos and uses non-standard null padding which is both insecure and will not work if the last byte of the data is 0x00.

For more information on PKCs#7 passing see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31859523/451475).

Early versions of `CCCrypt` would return an error if the padding was obviously incorrect, that was a security error which was later corrected. IIRC iOS7 was the last version that reported bad padding as an error.

Comment: I didn't know about the change in CCrypt. Do you have more on that? If padding is incorrect, what does it return?

Comment: This was covered several times in the Apple forums, Quinn was in many of the discussions. The issue is that some developers were using the error return to indicate a bad key. This worked fairly well based on PKCS#7 padding, a bad key had about a 255/256 (or so) chance of creating a padding error. But that is a security weakness so the parity check was removed and several developers were upset/hostile. Now if there is a parity error no error is reported. I'll see if I can find the discussions.

Comment: @RobNapier I fouud the reference to the padding error handling, here is a reference from the Apple forums by [gparker](https://devforums.apple.com/message/920802#920802): Enforcement of kCCDecodeError was removed for security reasons. (Look up "padding oracle attack".)  Also see the following response by Quinn.

Comment: Thanks. "or use an authenticated encryption algorithm." heh…yeah…http://www.openradar.me/11194903

Comment: Likewise, bugreport 21468609 but it seems Apple is not interested in updating iOS cryptography. EC is missing as well.