# AES128 truncated decrypted text on iOS 7, no problems on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, aes, commoncrypto

Using ciphertext encrypted with AES128 using ECB mode (this is toy encryption) and PKCS7 padding, the following code block results in the complete plaintext being recovered under iOS 8.

Running the same code block under iOS 7 results in the correct plaintext, but truncated. Why is this?

```
#import "NSData+AESCrypt.h" // <-- a category with the below function
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

- (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
    if (iv) {
        [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];                      
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;        
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr,               
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,   
                                          ivPtr,                
                                          [self bytes],
                                          dataLength,           
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,           
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);  
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

I've added a self-contained test harness below with results.

**Test harness:**

```
NSString *key = @"1234567890ABCDEF";
NSString *ciphertext = @"I9JIk5BskZMZKJFB/EAs+N2AYzkVR15DoBbUL7cBydBkWGlujVnzRHvBNvSVbcKh";

NSData *encData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:ciphertext options:0];
NSData *plainData = [encData AES128Operation:kCCDecrypt key:key iv:nil];

NSString *plaintext = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[plainData bytes]];

DLog(@"key: %@\nciphertext: %@\nplaintext: %@", key, ciphertext, plaintext);
```

**iOS 8 results:**

```
key: 1234567890ABCDEF
ciphertext: I9JIk5BskZMZKJFB/EAs+N2AYzkVR15DoBbUL7cBydBkWGlujVnzRHvBNvSVbcKh
plaintext: the quick brown fox jumped over the fence
```

**iOS 7 results:**

```
key: 1234567890ABCDEF
ciphertext: I9JIk5BskZMZKJFB/EAs+N2AYzkVR15DoBbUL7cBydBkWGlujVnzRHvBNvSVbcKh
plaintext: the quick brown fox jumped over 0
```

and subsequent results:

```
plaintext: the quick brown fox jumped over 
plaintext: the quick brown fox jumped over *
```

---

**Update:** Riddle me this: when I change

> kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode ⇒ kCCOptionECBMode

the results in iOS 7 are as expected. Why is this?? I know the number of bytes are block aligned because the ciphertext is padded with PKCS7 padding so this makes sense, but why does setting `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode` cause the truncated behavior in iOS 7 only?

---

**Edit:** The test ciphertext above was generated from both [this web site](http://aesencryption.net/), and independently using PHP's mcrypt with manual PKCS7 padding in the following function:

```
function encryptAES128WithPKCS7($message, $key)
{
    if (mb_strlen($key, '8bit') !== 16) {
        throw new Exception("Needs a 128-bit key!");
    }

    // Add PKCS7 Padding
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128);
    $pad = $block - (mb_strlen($message, '8bit') % $block);
    $message .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        $key,
        $message,
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
    );

    return $ciphertext;
}

// Demonstration encryption
echo base64_encode(encryptAES128WithPKCS7("the quick brown fox jumped over the fence", "1234567890ABCDEF"));
```

Out:

> I9JIk5BskZMZKJFB/EAs+N2AYzkVR15DoBbUL7cBydBkWGlujVnzRHvBNvSVbcKh

---

**Update:** The properly PKCS#7-padded ciphertext would be

> I9JIk5BskZMZKJFB/EAs+N2AYzkVR15DoBbUL7cBydA6aE5a3JrRst9Gn3sb3heC

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861024/1938889) is why is wasn't.

Comment: And the input data is identical on both versions?

Comment: @trojanfoe Absolutely. I'm using XCode 6 and I'm running the same app under the two aforementioned iOS simulators. I'm stepping through the code, and I've confirmed that the inputs and keys are identical down to the PKCS7 padding. The code is not modified between simulator runs.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've added a test harness to my question which reproduces the results I'm describing. What could cause the different behavior in ECB mode between iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Comment: In the call to `CCCrypt` you specify the key size with the define: `kCCBlockSizeAES128` but that is incorrect, the key size needs to be specified, not the block size. Use `kCCKeySizeAES128`.

Comment: BTW, using and extension does make this harder to test.

Comment: @zaph Thank you for the help. I checked, but `kCCKeySizeAES128 = 16` and `kCCBlockSizeAES128 = 16` in CommonCryptor.h

Comment: Yes, but you should use the correct define, you are just lucky this time.

Comment: @zaph I appreciate that. I'll suggest a patch for the category. FWIW, it's not my category to maintain. I'm tasked with identifying the discrepancy on this one.

Comment: Where/how is the encryption done? On another platform/language/library?

Comment: @zaph The ciphertext in the harness was generated identically by both PHP's mcrypt _with_ manual PKCS7 padding, and also by http://aesencryption.net/ for a comparison.

Comment: That explains everything, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is not encrypted with PKCS#7 padding but with null padding. You can tell this by logging `plainData`:

```
NSData *fullData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:dataLength];
NSLog(@"\nfullData: %@", fullData);
```

Output:
plainData: 74686520 71756963 6b206272 6f776e20 666f7820 6a756d70 6564206f 76657220 74686520 66656e63 65000000 00000000

The PHP mcrypt method does this, it is non-standard.

mcrypt(), while popular was written by some bozos and uses non-standard null padding which is both insecure and will not work if the last byte of the data is 0x00.

Early versions of CCCrypt would return an error if the padding was obviously incorrect, that was a security error which was later corrected. IIRC iOS7 was the last version that reported bad padding as an error.

The solution is to add PKCS#7 padding prior to encryption:

PKCS#7 padding always adds padding. The padding is a series by bytes with the value of the number of padding bytes added. The length of the padding is the block_size - (length(data) % block_size.

For AES where the block is is 16-bytes (and hoping the php is valid, it had been a while):

```
$pad_count = 16 - (strlen($data) % 16);
$data .= str_repeat(chr($pad_count), $pad_count);
```

Or remove trailing 0x00 bytes after decryption.

See [PKCS7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).

Early versions of CCCrypt would return an error if the padding was obviously incorrect, that was a security error which was later corrected. This was covered several times in the Apple forums, Quinn was in many of the discussions. But that is a security weakness so the parity check was removed and several developers were upset/hostile. Now if there is incorrect parity no error is reported.

Comment: You are absolutely right about mcrypt. I spent a day researching weaknesses of mcrypt and the phrase "written by some bozos" was memorable. ;) Please see my updated question which includes the PKCS#7 padding applied before `mcrypt_encrypt` is called. Perhaps it has a flaw?

Comment: Yes, your last edit uses a very similar manual PKCS7 padding to the one currently being used to generate the test data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've followed your past posts on similar topics. I'm here tasked with identifying why this blasted ECB encryption is returning the results specified in my post in iOS7, and if iOS 7 does have a bad padding error, I will need to hand over a ref to that effect... which would be good enough for this question at this time.

Comment: It is clear that the test data was not padded with PKCS#7 because it has null padding bytes. PKCS#7 passes with a bytes that are the length of the padding. `fullData ` would be: `74686520 71756963 6b206272 6f776e20 666f7820 6a756d70 6564206f 76657220 74686520 66656e63 65070707 07070707`

Comment: Quite right. Of all the stupid things that were given to me and assured to me, this has to be the most asinine. You deserve credit for diving deeper into the plain data to demonstrate that it is not, in fact, PKCS#7 padded when it was assured to be. I need to write up where the code fault lies.

Comment: "IIRC iOS7 was the last version that reported bad padding as an error." I'm going to need your best reference in the ballpark of that because neither iOS version reported an error, just happy truncation in iOS7. This needs to be officially cited for future work

Comment: All that needs to be cited is to insure that PKCS#7 padding is being added to the data prior to `mcrypt`. Otherwise go to thwe Apple Forums and ask about that, Quinn is well aware of the padding error issue.

Comment: Kindly humor me and add what your wrote in comments about the parity and security concerns in iOS 7 and iOS 8... as that is the title of the question which will be searched by future SO visitors - it needs to be a little different of an answer from a similar answer I came across ;) Good work again.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem with following code:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSData *_data;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"system version: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);

    NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i+=4)
    {
        [text appendFormat:@"ABCD"];
    }
    _data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *key = @"password";
    NSString *iv = @"12345678";
    NSData *encrypted = [self AES128Operation:kCCEncrypt key:key iv:iv];
    NSLog(@"encrypted: %@", encrypted);

    _data = encrypted;
    NSData *decrypted = [self AES128Operation:kCCDecrypt key:key iv:iv];
    NSLog(@"decrypted: %@ (%@)", decrypted, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decrypted encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
}

- (NSData *)AES128Operation:(CCOperation)operation key:(NSString *)key iv:(NSString *)iv
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    char ivPtr[kCCBlockSizeAES128 + 1];
    bzero(ivPtr, sizeof(ivPtr));
    if (iv) {
        [iv getCString:ivPtr maxLength:sizeof(ivPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    NSUInteger dataLength = [_data length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr,
                                          kCCBlockSizeAES128,
                                          ivPtr,
                                          [_data bytes],
                                          dataLength,
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    free(buffer);
    return nil;
}
```

Here are results:

```
2015-08-06 12:39:29.716 Test[37788:13220246] system version: 8.4
2015-08-06 12:39:29.717 Test[37788:13220246] encrypted: <17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 c6b4234e 1d0709c9 45113e4f 2a9607f7>
2015-08-06 12:39:29.717 Test[37788:13220246] decrypted: <41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344> (ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD)


2015-08-06 13:39:50.270 Test[37841:607] system version: 7.1
2015-08-06 13:39:50.272 Test[37841:607] encrypted: <17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 17445b45 da8b6f93 7787e80a 3feb6948 c6b4234e 1d0709c9 45113e4f 2a9607f7>
2015-08-06 13:39:50.273 Test[37841:607] decrypted: <41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344 41424344> (ABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCDABCD)
```

Also from documentation:

> Initialization vector, optional. Used for Cipher Block Chaining (CBC)
>   mode. If present, must be the same length as the selected algorithm's
>   block size. If CBC mode is selected (by the absence of any mode bits
>   in the options flags) and no IV is present, a NULL (all zeroes) IV
>   will be used. This is ignored if ECB mode is used or if a stream
>   cipher algorithm is selected.

So IV is useless in ECB mode.

Comment: I've added a test harness to my question with does reproduce the results I'm describing. Also, I'm not using CBC mode, and iv is nil and ignored in ECB mode. What could cause the different behavior **in ECB mode** between iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Comment: ECB mode does not use an iv. If you want a good and free book get the [*Handbook of Applied Cryptography*](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/), it is a free download.

Comment: @Drakes it is good idea to mention in question that you use encryption from another application.

Answer (score 0):

[Dead to rights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31859523/1938889) it turns out that there is a subtle flaw with the **manual** PKCS#7 padding routine applied before PHP's mcrypt.

It is [well-known](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#47973) that mcrypt uses null padding, so to make it PKCS7-compatible mcrypt required manually byte-aligning the data by appending `n` number of bytes containing the value `n` in each of them. In the case of this question, it was done with this gem of code:

```
// Add PKCS#7 Padding
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128);
$pad = $block - (mb_strlen($message, '8bit') % $block);
$message .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(
    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
    $key,
    $message,
    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
);
```

We're doing the right thing here, *aren't we?* I was required to focus on the iOS 7/8 problem. However, it turns out

```
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128); // null
```

does nothing when linked against newer versions of libmcrypt >= 2.4 ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-block-size.php)), but

```
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'ecb'); // 16
```

properly returns the block size. In effect, no padding is being applied and padding reverts to null padding a la mcrypt. Credit goes to [zaph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31859523/1938889) for demonstrating

> It is clear that the test data was not padded with PKCS#7 because it
>   has null padding bytes. PKCS#7 passes with a bytes that are the length
>   of the padding. fullData would be: 74686520 71756963 6b206272 6f776e20
>   666f7820 6a756d70 6564206f 76657220 74686520 66656e63 65070707
>   07070707

Now, there was mention of iOS 7 handling "bad padding" differently than iOS 8. I *absolutely* need a reference on that, but these two faults combined explain the behavior observed in the OP.

Comment: Early versions of CCCrypt would return an error if the padding was obviously incorrect, that was a security error which was later corrected. IIRC iOS7 was the last version that reported bad padding as an error. This was covered several times in the Apple forums, Quinn was in many of the discussions. But that is a security weakness so the parity check was removed and several developers were upset/hostile. Now if there is incorrect parity no error is reported.

Comment: @zaph Good enough. Kindly put this in your answer as it resolves the iOS 7 problem and I will accept it. THANK YOU so much for staying on this, and for dumping the NSData. Good work.